# Extract keys from json

Tags: python, json

I am creating the score web app in the python framework flask. So I have a JSON file with the following content

```
{
    "page1": {
        "pr": {
            "user": "A",
            "timestamp": "2017-02-23T23:08:53Z"
        },
        ...
    },
    "page2": {
        "pr": {
            "user": "A",
            "timestamp": "2017-02-23T23:11:01Z"
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

I am reading the file by this in python

```
    with open("result.json", encoding="utf8") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
```

I want to extract "page" keys of "pr" in respect of "user" and save into another JSON file with the following content

```
{
    "A": { page1, page2, ...},
    "B": { page1, page2, ...},
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you have?

Comment: is "user" always at the same hierarchy level of your json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple answer:

```
 res = {}
 for page in data:
     user = data[page]["pr"]["user"]
     if user not in res:
        res[user] = [page]
     else:
        res[user].append(page)
 print(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

Oi, just for the challenge ;-).

Although there is a simplier way to just register pages that the users visited, I'll here post a functional way.

The data structure that you posted seems not that complicated and I think the following should work for you. First you need a list of data samples. Each sample contains page and user. Then you can simply group by user and retrieve entries as necessary for further processing.

```
import toolz
import toolz.curried

stuff = {
    "page1": {
        "pr": {
            "user": "A",
            "timestamp": "2017-02-23T23:08:53Z"
        }
    },
    "page2": {
        "pr": {
            "user": "A",
            "timestamp": "2017-02-23T23:11:01Z"
        }
    },
    "page3": {
        "pr": {
            "user": "b",
            "timestamp": "2017-02-23T23:11:01Z"
        }
    }
}

transformed_stuff = [{'page': page, **value} for page, value in stuff.items()]
get_user = toolz.curried.get_in(['pr', 'user'])
toolz.groupby(get_user, transformed_stuff)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the pages, retrieve users and create a new dictionary:

**Note:** if only one `pr` can exist under a `page` then the second `for loop` can be avoided. Otherwise, go with two loops as shown below.

```
import json

with open("../data/page-data.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
output = {}
for page in data:
    for pr in data[page]:
        user = data[page][pr]['user']
        if user not in output:
            output[user] = [page]
        else:
            output[user].append(page)

print(json.dumps(output))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) using a set as the default constructor.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(set)

for page, json_data in data.items():
    user = json_data.get('pr', {}).get('user')
    dd[user] = dd[user].union([page])

>>> dict(dd)
{'A': {'page1', 'page2'}}
```